# Google Oauth consent screen doesn't show up

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I'm trying to follow the Google Oauth guide to give my Rails app permission to edit users' calendars. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#step-2:-send-a-request-to-googles-oauth-2.0-server) seems to say that all you have to do is send a certain request to the Google API, and that will prompt the consent screen to pop up for the user. However, I'm sending the request with no errors, but nothing happens.

My app has been verified, and the URL I'm attempting this on has been added to my Oauth credentials. Theoretically in this instance it shouldn't matter, but I also have the 'google-api-client', 'omniauth', and 'omniauth-google-oauth2' gems installed. The URL is HTTPS with an SSL cert.

What am I doing wrong?

```
# this is the controller action for my path, so the API is pinged when the page is loaded
def path

    url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
      scope=email%20profile%20calendar.events&
      response_type=code&
      redirect_uri=<URL>&
      client_id=<CLIENT_ID>"

    require 'open-uri'
    require 'uri'
    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'
    require 'net/https'
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)


end
```

Comment: How could Python code running on the server open a window in the client browser? The window pops up, when you use the JavaScript client.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr The guide doesn't say anything about a Javascript client. It literally says to ping that API, and the next step is a popup for the user. What Javascript client are you referring to, and how can I implement it?

Comment: Your app is running on your server with IP 1.2.3.4 and by sending a request to Google and that opens a browser window on a users laptop with the IP 5.6.7.8? How should that work? How could I from my computer authorize your app on yours? Try to find a better tutorial for your use case.

Comment: And, yes, it's Ruby, not Python code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide is a little confusing. They say "send a request to the URL https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth" but actually mean "open that URL in a browser".  I think that is the point that you misunderstood.

So, create this html file:

```html
<a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=email%20profile%20calendar.events&response_type=code&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&client_id=CLIENT_ID">Login
with Google</a>
```

Now open the html file in a browser and click the link.  You will notice that the Google server redirects the browser to the REDIRECT_URI you have specified.  Either you can see that in your web server logs (if the server works) or the browser will display an error message and you can see the URL with all query parameters sent by Google in the browser address bar.

See in the docs what your server has to respond to the redirected request so that the consent screen finally shows up.

When it shows up, the procedure is similar: You - as the user - grant the permissions requested, and when you click the button, Google will respond again with a redirect, and you then harvest the token from the query parameters.

Comment: Wooow, thanks so much for this! Should've known it was that simple. I use APIs so often I forget there are other ways.

Comment: It also took me some time to understand what the Google guys actually meant with "send a request to us ...". So don't worry and happy coding!