# How to initiate OAuth2.0 flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-drive-api

How do I POST to Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoints for authorization?

I'm building a chrome extension in React and have been following [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#redirecting). It seems pretty straightforward but I'm not fully grasping the mechanics of the implementation.

For example, in my popup.js file I call my background.js file which performs and axios POST request to the created redirect url. Step 3 in the guide says that Google will prompt the user for consent, however, that never happens. I get a 200 response but not sure where to go after that.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
  axios
      .post(
        `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
         scope=https%3A//www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly&
         include_granted_scopes=true&
         response_type=token&
         state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
         redirect_uri=https%3A//oauth2.example.com/code& 
         client_id=client_id` //actual values added
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('RESPONSE', response);
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 2 in that document is titled

> Step 2: Redirect to Google's OAuth 2.0 server

You are trying to do an XHR request with `POST`.

The document provides sample code both with and without their client library. Without the client library, you can see that it is a `GET` request using a form (which changes the URL in the browser, effectively redirecting):

```
/*
 * Create form to request access token from Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
 */
function oauthSignIn() {
  // Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoint for requesting an access token
  var oauth2Endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';

  // Create <form> element to submit parameters to OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
  var form = document.createElement('form');
  form.setAttribute('method', 'GET'); // Send as a GET request.
  form.setAttribute('action', oauth2Endpoint);

  // Parameters to pass to OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
  var params = {'client_id': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
                'redirect_uri': 'YOUR_REDIRECT_URI',
                'response_type': 'token',
                'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
                'include_granted_scopes': 'true',
                'state': 'pass-through value'};

  // Add form parameters as hidden input values.
  for (var p in params) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    input.setAttribute('name', p);
    input.setAttribute('value', params[p]);
    form.appendChild(input);
  }

  // Add form to page and submit it to open the OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had implemented the example code above before attempting to (incorrectly) axios post. My hangup was that I wasn't sure where to go once that function was called. For example, ```<button onClick={() => oauthSignIn()}>GRANT ACCESS</button>```. The docs state ```the snippet creates a form that opens the request to that endpoint.``` before going into step 3 regarding the google popup. Should calling that function initiate the popup or am I misunderstanding that as well?

Comment: once you redirect the user, google will handle the user input and redirect back to whatever you define as YOUR_REDIRECT_URL. Then your application will have to handle google's request along with the query parameters (see step 4).

Comment: Doing more research, it simply looks like the link needs to be opened in order preset the consent screen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761064/google-oauth-consent-screen-doesnt-show-up. Thanks for the help, I'm on the right track now :)

Comment: Yep opening it in the browser is the simplest approach. You're welcome!